# Initial SessionFactory creation failed

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I know this question has been asked before but all the responses did not fix my issue. So I am asking mine in the hope of getting help from much more experienced Java programmers. I have been trying to run a simple hibernate code with hibernate 4 but I have been getting the same error.

```
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:33 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Emp/entity/Emp.hbm.xml
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:34 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Dec 17, 2014 4:12:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Emp.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:39)
    at Emp.Ui.IntroForm.executeHQL(IntroForm.java:93)
    at Emp.Ui.IntroForm.runQuery(IntroForm.java:88)
    at Emp.Ui.IntroForm.jButton3ActionPerformed(IntroForm.java:106)
    at Emp.Ui.IntroForm.access$000(IntroForm.java:18)
    at Emp.Ui.IntroForm$1.actionPerformed(IntroForm.java:45)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022) at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at Emp.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:35)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 55 more
```

**Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYNAME-PC/sqlpractice;instance=NAMESQLEXPRESS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Here's my hibernate.reveng.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="sqlpractice" match-schema="dbo"/>
  <table-filter match-name="Emp"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**Here's my Hibernate.Util file:**

```
package Emp.util;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


    static {

        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            //sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }


    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is unable to find the jtds Driver class on the class path.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested
>   class : net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Make sure you have the jtds jar on the classpath so Hibernate can load the class.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked when I added the jtds jar file to the classpath.